# G5 running Mac OS X 10.3.5 won't update the OS

Tags: macos, software-update, powerpc, panther

I have a Power Mac G5 running OS X Panther. If I open Finder and click 'Software Updates', the progress bar gets about half way across and then quits with the message "an error occurred while checking for updates". The machine has a working Internet connection.

What could be the problem and how might I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Try [Mac OS X Combined Update 10.3.9](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl496?locale=en_US)